# SHA-2 and Solaris 10 u8 compatibility

Tags: unix, solaris-10

I'm doing a deployment and have some questions about SHA-2 and Solaris 10 u8 server.

Is SHA-2 compatible with Solaris 10 u8 64 bit? 
If not, why? Is there a Solaris patch that would allow SHA-2?
What steps should be taken?

Answer (score 1):

SHA-2 is an encryption algorithm. The question of whether it is "compatible" with an operating system is orthogonal. I believe what you're really asking is "can I use the SHA-2 algorithm on Solaris 10u8".

The answer is, yes, you can, on both x64 and Sparc. No special patch is required.

You don't say, however, what utility/application/... you want to make use of
SHA-2 with.